# Specific violin sound effect often used in anime, when something heavy is revealed in a comic way

Tags: sound-effects

https://www.watchcartoononline.io/boku-no-hero-academia-season-2-episode-6-english-subbed
At 10:56 there is a violin sound effect that often can be heard in anime (and maybe other media, not sure).
I imagine it's a part of a piece. Does anybody recognise it and/or knows the name of it?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't sound like a violin to me, although there is a violin or viola piece just after it, in the next scene. It sounds like a generic, rising synth hit effect with a concert tom(drum) layered below and the classic orchestral wind chimes above.

They probably got the main generic hit off some sample library then just added the delay effect that can also be heard and then layered it with the other sounds mentioned. It would be quite easy to recreate a close example or find a similar effect in an FX library.

The biggest impact I think comes from the concert tom. You often get a standard or rising tom hit on a comic reveal of large, bouncy or wobbly objects similar to the ones in the video.